# How to get Sublime Text seeing all the methods/functions available

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I can't see the available functions and methods for this variable when I type `name.`. I want Sublime Text to show me available functions and methods for this variable just like Anaconda does.

I've already installed the Anaconda package and enabled it, so it doesn't make any sense to me. I'm also aware of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> function which doesn't show me anything or help me about any function or method.

I'm looking for an option which will show me all possible methods and functions when I type `.` after any variable or a shortcut to show me all possible functions and methods.